# Understanding direct and indirect blocks?

Tags: memory, inode, data

Why can't we use use indirect blocks instead of direct blocks. Indirect blocks can store much more memory addresses which results in more data blocks. So why waste those 10 direct blocks in Inode table of contents when we can do the the job of those in a single indirect block.

Comment: Enjoy learning about extent-based filesystems.  (-:

Answer (score 1):

Because an indirect block requires another block allocated, and another block to read from disk. So it costs disk space and access time.